Spring Boot Angular18 Uploading Photo
Hey Guys I'm trying to do Full-stack website by myself actually ı'm spring developer and ı try to learn angular let's have a look my problem my code is working but it is very slow ı upload photo the program but it can not appear,sometimes it went to 40 - 60 seconds i think it is not normal when ı clicked the upload button it is saved in database but it won't show up in front end web page i will send my back end and front end code does anyone get this error before ?
<div class="row">
    <!-- Product Image -->
     <div class="col-md-6 product-image">
      <img *ngIf="product.imageUrl; else uploadPhoto" [src]="product.imageUrl"  class="img-fluid rounded shadow-lg">
      <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="loading-overlay">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
      
      <ng-template #uploadPhoto>
        <div class="upload-container">
          <label class="upload-photo-btn">
            <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" id="photoUpload" hidden>
            <span>Upload Photo</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      
    </div>

 onFileSelected(event: Event): void {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (input?.files?.length) {
      const file = input.files[0];
  
      // Yükleme başladığında isLoading'yi true yapıyoruz
      this.isLoading = true;
  
      // Fotoğraf yükleme servisini çağırıyoruz
      this.productService.uploadPhoto(this.product.id, file).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          // Fotoğraf başarıyla yüklendiyse, URL'yi güncelliyoruz
          this.product.imageUrl = response;
          console.log("Fotoğraf başarıyla yüklendi: ", response);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          // Hata durumunda kullanıcıya uygun bir mesaj gösteriyoruz
          this.isLoading = false; // Hata oluştuğunda spinner'ı kapatıyoruz
          if (error.status === 400) {
            alert('Geçersiz dosya formatı veya dosya boyutu fazla. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.');
          } else if (error.status === 500) {
            alert('Sunucu hatası oluştu. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin.');
          } else {
            alert('Fotoğraf yüklenirken bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.');
          }
          console.error("Fotoğraf yüklenirken hata oluştu: ", error);
        },
        complete: () => {
          // Yükleme işlemi tamamlandıktan sonra spinner'ı kapatıyoruz
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }

uploadPhoto(productId:number,file:File) : Observable<string> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',file,file.name);

    return this.http.post<string>(`http://localhost:8080/v1/photos/upload/${productId}`, formData,{responseType: 'text' as 'json' });

  }

Application Properties :
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=60s
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=3MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=3MB
file.upload-dir = src/main/resources/static/uploads

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/photos")
public class FileStorageController {


    private final FileStorageService fileStorageService;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;


    public FileStorageController(FileStorageService fileStorageService, ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.fileStorageService = fileStorageService;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadfile(@PathVariable int id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile){
            try {
                Product product = productRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IdNotFoundException(id));
                String photoUrl = fileStorageService.saveFile(multipartFile);
                product.setImageUrl(photoUrl);
                productRepository.save(product);

               return ResponseEntity.ok(photoUrl);
            }catch (Exception e){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }


}

@Service
public class FileStorageService {

    private final String uploadDir;
    private final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 3 * 1024 * 1024 ;
    // Constructor with @Value to read upload directory from application.properties
    public FileStorageService(@Value("${file.upload-dir}") String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = Paths.get(uploadDir).toAbsolutePath().toString();
    }

    public String saveFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File is empty!");
        }

        if(file.getSize() > MAX_FILE_SIZE){
            throw new RuntimeException("File size exceeds the maximum allowed size of 3 MB.");
        }
        // Generate a unique file name
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
        Path filePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, fileName);

        // Create directories if they don't exist
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());

        Files.write(filePath, file.getBytes());

        return "/uploads/" + fileName;
    }
}

I'm expecting to solve my problem or make more faster my web application

Doesn't seem all that slow to me... depends on the size of the file.... maybe use file.transferTo(filePath); instead. Maybe also confirm the absolute path is correct before running createDirectories... (and that it matches relative front-end of "/uploads/" + fileName;)  Is there a get root directory method in Spring? (on a side note I would not trust file.getOriginalFilename... be sure to be in full control of the filename and especially the extension)

I already try this file.transferTo(filePath)  solution but it still up to 20 second to upload

bro do you have any idea why ı get this warning from back-end
2024-12-10T22:03:59.770+03:00  WARN 80384 --- [E-commerce] [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]

not familiar with Spring, but I'd guess this happens when client aborts the upload.  Looks like it's just a WARN, so nothing to do there.  (You can't control the client end...)

If you continue to have troubles, I would also remove the headers you set on post... ",{responseType: 'text' as 'json' }"  is not necessary and the FormData object automatically sets the headers.

ı remove this {responseType: 'text' as 'json' } code but the application still the same situation nothing changed do you have different idea or would you share this post for me

After a couple of weeks of research, I realized that I don't get an error when I upload PNG format. The issue occurs when I try to upload JPEG format.Problem solved

After a couple of weeks of research, I realized that I don't get an error when I upload PNG format. The issue occurs when I try to upload JPEG format.Problem solved
